# Recursive function responding different value

Tags: java, recursion

I wrote a java recursive function to get sum of a number as follows, and the sum should be single digit as well.the problem i am facing here is it should return the else part at the end where as it is giving the after if else condition return statement:

```
static int recSum(int n){
    int sum = 0;
    while(n!=0){
        sum += n%10;
        n = n/10;
    }

    if(sum>9) { 
        recSum(sum); 
    } 
    else { 
        return sum; 
    }
       return sum ;
```

}

Let us say n = 12345 so at the end it needs to return 5 where as it is returning 14. However it is going to the else part but the correct value is not returning. I got the solution with the ternary operator without else loop. but would like to what is the reason for this i am getting the previous sum of 14 rather 5 (5 comes from  14 = 1+4)

Appreciate the response on this

Comment: I'm not sure why you discard the return value of recSum on some control paths. Also note that Java function parameters are passed by value. Clearly written question imho. I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: @Umadhar, your `while` loop in recursion method is making it run iteratively and removes the purpose for recursion. Check my corrected answer. Thanks.

Comment: In the `if`, you calculate `recSum(sum)` but never do anything with the result. Did you mean to assign its value to `sum`? Remember that Java is _never_ pass-by-reference, so if you call `recSum(sum)`, then the `n` in the recSum call is a copy of `sum` -- and does not modify it as far as the caller is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

The change you should do is fairly simple: you should remove the last `return` statement and just return the result of recursive call:

```
static int recSum(int n){
    int sum = 0;
    while(n!=0){
        sum += n%10;
        n = n/10;
    }

    if(sum>9) { 
        return recSum(sum); 
    } 
    else { 
        return sum; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Compilation error if i do not have the return statement.

Comment: @UmadharM Look at the code I've posted. Both `if` and `else` have `return` statements.

Comment: @UmadharM it should compile just fine, if not, maybe your compiler is outdated.
You can always keep the last return statement, as long as you have return recSum(sum);

Answer (score 0):

When this function gets to the if statement and calls the function again the 15 is saved on the stack until the current call is finished, when the current call is finished the previous answer was 15 so it's returning that because you dont modify it in anyway after it gets returned.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, However once the recursive call is made, it is modifying the sum internally, Could you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an iterative way (NOT a good way to build recursion in your program)

```
    while (n != 0) {
        sum += n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
    }
```

This is the correct recursive way and works even for 0 and negative numbers.

```
static int recSum(int n) {
    int sum = 0;

    sum = sum + (n % 10);
    n = n / 10;

    if (n != 0) {
        return sum + recSum(n);
    } else {
        return sum;
    }
}
```